# Alternative logical operator for more than two inputs with check value

Tags: javascript

I have script in JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#new_logo_box').click(function (event) {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#basic_info').slideDown(400); }
    else {
      $('#basic_info').slideUp(400);}
    });                                        
   });
</script>
```

Now I want to check more than one input with alternative logical operator. How should I do that? I was trying with:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#new_logo_box').click(function (event) ||
       $('#renew_logo_box').click(function (event) {
        if (this.checked) {
          $('#basic_info').slideDown(400); }
        else {
          $('#basic_info').slideUp(400);}
        });                                        
       });
</script>
```

but this is not working...

Comment: What’s the exact expected behaviour here? You want `#basic_info` to appear when *either* `#new_logo_box` or `#renew_logo_box` is checked?

Comment: Yeah, exactly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select each element separately and use [`add`](https://api.jquery.com/add) to add the event listener to both of them:

```
var newLogoBox = $('#new_logo_box');
var renewLogoBox = $('#renew_logo_box');

newLogoBox.add(renewLogoBox).on('change', function () {
    if (newLogoBox.prop('checked') || renewLogoBox.prop('checked')) {
        $('#basic_info').slideDown(400);
    } else {
        $('#basic_info').slideUp(400);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just list all items you want to apply the event handler to in a single selector like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#new_logo_box, #renew_logo_box').click(function (event){
    if (this.checked) 
      $('#basic_info').slideDown(400);         
    else 
      $('#basic_info').slideUp(400);
   });
  });
```

Using this, your logic will be executed when any of the items listed is clicked.

To match your need to hide the basic info only if nothing is checked, you can use something like this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
   var counter = 0;
   $('#new_logo_box, #renew_logo_box').click(function (event){
    if (this.checked) 
      counter++;
    else 
      counter--;

    if (counter > 0) 
      $('#basic_info').slideDown(400);         
    else 
      $('#basic_info').slideUp(400);
   });
  });
```

Using this approach, you can add as many elements to your event handler as needed without needing to adapt your event handler.

Comment: Ok, this is something, but: when #new_logo_box and #renew_logo_box are checked and when let's say I unckeck #new_logo_box then #basic_info disappear. And I want that but only when both inputs are not checked.